# "Use of unresolved identifier" with Swift

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am rewriting one of my apps in Swift, that displays live weather data for South Kohala. Love Swift so far!

I'm having one small problem that is holding things up. I have a tab bar based app, iPad only.

One of my tabs is a `UIViewController` with a `TableView` added to it in the storyboard to display NOAA forecasts. I have a data class `Data` that retrieves the list from our server and creates a constant `List` in `viewDidLoad`.  It is an array of arrays with four strings in each subarray.

I have verified that it's there, as I can create a constant: `List[0]` and `println` all the strings.

However, when I go to use it to populate the table view, I get a "Use of unresolved identifier" error. If instead, I try setting the cell Title to "Test" that works OK.

This seems like a scope issue, but as the constant is created within the class, I just don't understand why it's not visible in the `tableView` function. I've looked at dozens of posts on this, but nothing I have found seems to help. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ForecastsViewController: UIViewController,   UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var forecastsTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let instanceofData: Data = Data()
        let list = instanceofData.forecastsList() as NSArray
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
      var forecastList:NSArray = list[indexPath.row] //selects one of the arrays from List
      cell.textLabel?.text = forecastList[0] as string
           return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

It is because `List` is purely local to the inside of `viewDidLoad`; where you've *declared* it, other methods cannot see it.

Contrast, for example, `forecastsTable`, which is declared *outside* any method, which means that any method can see it.

This behavior is called "scope" and is crucial to any programming language. Variables *declared* inside a method are neither visible outside it nor do they persist when that method has finished running. Thus, in your example, not only is `List` not *visible* when `cellForRowAtIndex` runs, it doesn't even *exist* when `cellForRowAtIndex` runs - it has been destroyed long before.

Comment: By the way, don't start the name of a variable (`List`) with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I thought that a variable declared in viewDidLoad was available to other functions.

Comment: And now you know that that was wrong. A globally visible variable _set_ in an earlier function has that value visible to a later function, but a local variable is not globally visible — by definition.