# How to pass JSON to a function from viewDidLoad function?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Inside of viewDidLoad I get the JSON with the following code:

```
request(.POST, "example.com", parameters: device).response { (request, response, data, error) in
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

        var myJSON = JSON(data:data! as! NSData)
}
```

And in the bottom I have a function `answer()`:

```
func answer() {
    if queue+1 <= 3 {
        var questionBodyText = myJSON["result"][queue]["body"].stringValue
        var variantAText = myJSON["result"][queue]["var_a"].stringValue
        var variantBText = myJSON["result"][queue]["var_b"].stringValue
        var variantCText = myJSON["result"][queue]["var_c"].stringValue
        var variantDText = myJSON["result"][queue]["var_d"].stringValue
    }
}
```

but I cannot use in answer() the `myJSON` it prints, that `Use of unresolved identifier myJSON` error.

So, my question is, how can I 'see' this myJSON data from the answer() function and use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Use of unresolved identifier" with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343742/use-of-unresolved-identifier-with-swift)

Answer (score 1):

`myJSON` is declared in the response block and cannot be accessed outside this block. Declare a variable outside (e.g. in your class) and set this variable with your json data.

EDIT

Declare like (outside block) :

```
var myJSON:JSON?
```

and in your request :

```
request(.POST, "http://example.com", parameters: device).response { (request, response, data, error) in
    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

    myJSON = JSON(data:data! as! NSData)
}
```

Comment: I did try it, like `var json = [Dictionary<String, String>]()`, but I couldn't use it again. I couldn't append myJSON into this dictionary. How can I do it?

Comment: `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON?' with an index of type 'String'` error in `myJSON?["result"][queue]["body"].stringValue` line

Comment: nvm see @skyline75489

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController declare myJSON as a property:

```
class ViewController {
    var myJSON:JSON?
}
```

assign value:

```
myJSON = JSON(data:data! as! NSData)
```

and use it:

```
if let j = myJSON {
    var questionBodyText = j["result"][queue]["body"].stringValue
}
```

Comment: `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON?' with an index of type 'String'` error in `myJSON?["result"][queue]["body"].stringValue` line

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Are you using SwiftyJSON?

Comment: it works now, but it's(myJSON) outside of the .POST request block is nil. How to fix it?

Comment: `myJSON` is an optional. If you want to access its value, you need to unwrap it like above using something like `if let j = myJSON`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76036/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-skyline75489).