# How to add done button the decimal pad in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

How to add a custom done button on the IOS decimal pad that I am using for my app.I've tried using screen touch to dismiss,but found it efficient.So if you can write a code in swift it would mean the world to me, and thank you in advance.There are help for this problem but all of them are in Objective-c which I don't know.

Comment: oi @Dharmesh Kheni why did you mark this as duplicate, there is no another question like this. If so show me the link then

Comment: Link is already there.

Comment: oi @DharmeshKheni The solution is for UI date picker, I specifically asked for Decimal pad if you don't wanna help it is alright but why mark it as duplicate then

Comment: Just read accepted answer carefully.. :)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni you are right I read it carefully it works but there is a small problem love, "item.tintColor = UIColor .yellowColor()", This bit of the code gives me an error says "Unsolved identifier" how can I fix it

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343742/use-of-unresolved-identifier-with-swift